# What is dislocation loop?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science

What is dislocation loop? Is it something different from dislocations? If so can dislocations at higher temperature can combine to form dislocation loop?

Answer (score 1):

a dislocation loop is a linear dislocation in which its two ends meet together- that is, it's still a dislocation in the crystal lattice but by closing in on itself it has special propagation properties, about which entire chapters of upper-division materials science textbooks have been written.

Years ago, a team of Japanese materials scientists and electron microscopists made a movie using transmission electron microscopy which actually shows dislocation loop propagation as a function of applied stresses. If I can find a copy on-line I will edit & link it to this answer.

Comment: Frank-Read sources pump out dislocation loops under appropriate stresses, and there are some good TEM videos of their operation as well. Not in a position to search at the moment...

Comment: yes yes, I saw one of those fabulous TEM videos in grad school 41 years ago!

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my doubts.